# Why run time error in program?

Tags: python, testing, palindrome

In a problem on HackerRank, where the number of Palindrome substring is to be counted.

This program works well, tried with different test cases.

But it's not passing the last two test cases on HackerRank.

What can be the possible Test Cases which my program failed to execute successfully.

Here's the problem statement.

**It has 1 parameter: a string, s. It must return an integer denoting the number of palindromic substrings of s.**

**Constraints**

**1 ≤ |S| ≤ 5 × (10)^3 s is composed of lowercase English letters.**

**Output Format**

**Your function must return an integer denoting the number of different palindromic substrings of s**

```
def countPalindromes(s):
    counter=0
    length = len(s)
    list1= ([s[i:j+1] for i in range(length) for j in range(i,length)])
    list2=([x[::-1] for x in list1])
    for i in range(len(list2)):
        if(list1[i]==list2[i]):
            counter+=1
    return counter

#input = aaa
#output = 6 i.e. {a,a,a,aa,aa,aaa}
#input = abccba
#output = 9
#input = daata
#output = 7
#output is correct though failing the last 2 test cases
```

Comment: What is the function supposed to do?

Comment: Count the total palindrome substrings. Look the comments in End

Comment: Surely you had a more detailed specification when you wrote the code. It's impossible to see what might be wrong with it now.

Comment: What is the name of the challenge?

Comment: Provide a link or something to the hacker rank website.

Comment: This is the exact problem statement @UbdusSamad

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) and [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to calculate the number of palindrome substrings in a string. For example:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    return 1 if s == s[::-1] else 0


def count_palindromes(s, i, j, m):
    key = '{}-{}'.format(i, j)
    if key in m.keys():
        return m[key]
    if i == len(s)-1 or i > j:
        return 0
    m[key] = is_palindrome(s[i:j]) + count_palindromes(s, i+1, j, m) + count_palindromes(s, i, j-1, m)
    return m[key]


m = {}
print(count_palindromes('aaa', 0, 2, m)) # should be count_palindromes(s, 0, len(s)-1, m)
# output: 6
```